# Form validation with Spring Security login page

Tags: java, spring, validation, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have created a simple login page and configured `Spring` Security to use it. But actually I can submit an empty form. I don't want that. I need to show validation messages on the text fields. The user must not be able to trigger the expensive authentication mechanism by just submitting an empty form.

How can I do that?

I followed this tutorial-
https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.0.RELEASE/guides/form.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add [`required` attribute](http://www.the-art-of-web.com/html/html5-form-validation/) to the login and password fields. In this case browser won't let to submit form with empty fields. But this is a client side technology and thus users still can submit such empty requests manually or from the browsers that don't support this attribute (like Safari).

Because you're dealing with Spring Security you can't use controllers and even interceptors from Spring MVC because they're executed after Spring Security's filter.

I suggest you to write a custom filter, put it before Spring Security's filters and handle the case with empty form manually.

As an example of how to write filter and how to register it in the Spring Boot application you may use this commit from my pet project: [4020099d](https://github.com/php-coder/mystamps/commit/4020099d936567180a0fe1a464dfdfefe6574f72) In your case, code will be simpler.

Comment: I hoped there is an easy "Spring" way, too bad. I'll take a look at the filter solution. Thank you.